# Attribute Error: 'PdfFileReader' object has no attribute '_checkKids'

Tags: python, pypdf

I am new in Python, and pretty new in programming too. Any advise would be very helpful.
I used a script to read a pdf file and extract a javascript file to use for form autofilling.
I have installed PyPDF2 module , but I am getting this error

An error occured... :( 'PdfFileReader' object has no attribute '_checkKids'

Here is the code I am using :

```
import os
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

def _getFields(obj, tree=None, retval=None, fileobj=None):
    fieldAttributes = {'/FT': 'Field Type', '/Parent': 'Parent', '/T': 'Field Name', '/TU': 
'Alternate Field Name',
                       '/TM': 'Mapping Name', '/Ff': 'Field Flags', '/V': 'Value', '/DV': 
'Default Value'}
    if retval is None:
        retval = OrderedDict()
        catalog = obj.trailer["/Root"]
    if "/AcroForm" in catalog:
        tree = catalog["/AcroForm"]
    else:
        return None
if tree is None:
    return retval

obj._checkKids(tree, retval, fileobj)
for attr in fieldAttributes:
    if attr in tree:
       obj._buildField(tree, retval, fileobj, fieldAttributes)
       break

if "/Fields" in tree:
    fields = tree["/Fields"]
    for f in fields:
        field = f.getObject()
        obj._buildField(field, retval, fileobj, fieldAttributes)

return retval

def get_form_fields(infile):
    infile = PdfFileReader(open(infile, 'rb'))
    fields = _getFields(infile)
    return OrderedDict((k, v.get('/V', '')) for k, v in fields.items())

def selectListOption(all_lines, k, v):
    all_lines.append('function setSelectedIndex(s, v) {')
    all_lines.append('for (var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++) {')
    all_lines.append('if (s.options[i].text == v) {')
    all_lines.append('s.options[i].selected = true;')
    all_lines.append('return;') 
    all_lines.append('}')
    all_lines.append('}')
    all_lines.append('}')
    all_lines.append('setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("' + k + '"), "' + v + '");')

def readList(fname):
    lst = []
    with open(fname, 'r') as fh:  
        for l in fh:
            lst.append(l.rstrip(os.linesep))
    return lst

def createBrowserScript(fl, fl_ext, items, pdf_file_name):
    if pdf_file_name and len(fl) > 0:
        of = os.path.splitext(pdf_file_name)[0] + '.txt'
        all_lines = []
        for k, v in items.items():
            print(k + ' -> ' + v)
        if (v in ['/Yes', '/On']):
            all_lines.append("document.getElementById('" + k + "').checked = true;\n");
        elif (v in ['/0'] and k in fl_ext):
            all_lines.append("document.getElementById('" + k + "').checked = true;\n");
        elif (v in ['/No', '/Off', '']):
            all_lines.append("document.getElementById('" + k + "').checked = false;\n");
        elif (v in [''] and k in fl_ext):
            all_lines.append("document.getElementById('" + k + "').checked = false;\n");
        elif (k in fl):
            selectListOption(all_lines, k, v)
        else:
            all_lines.append("document.getElementById('" + k + "').value = '" + v + "';\n");
    outF = open(of, 'w')
    outF.writelines(all_lines)
    outF.close()

def execute(args):
    try: 
        fl = readList('myview.ini')
        fl_ext = readList('myview_ext.ini')
        if len(args) == 2:
            pdf_file_name = args[1]
            items = get_form_fields(pdf_file_name)
            createBrowserScript(fl, fl_ext, items, pdf_file_name)
        else:
            files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith('.pdf')]
            for f in files:
                items = get_form_fields(f)
                createBrowserScript(fl, fl_ext, items, f)
    except BaseException as msg:
        print('An error occured... :( ' + str(msg))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pprint import pprint
    execute(sys.argv)
```

Comment: What version of `PyPDF2` are you using?

Comment: What is your goal with calling checkKids?

Comment: I am using Version 2.11.10 . Python Version is the latest 3.10.7

Comment: `_checkKids` was changed to `_check_kids` in [1.28](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/meta/CHANGELOG.html#version-1-28-0-2022-05-22). It looks like that method is intended to be private anyway.

Comment: Problem solved, changing names to _checkKids and _buildField to _check_kids and _build_field.  They changed names to methods when they updated the version of PyPDF2. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is being triggered because you call:

```
    obj._checkKids(tree, retval, fileobj)
```

_checkKids has an underscore in front of it.  This indicates that the function is meant to be used internally within the class and shouldn't be called externally.

In python, this means:

"1. Single Leading Underscore:

When it comes to variable and method names, the single underscore prefix has a meaning by convention only. It’s a hint to the programmer—and it means what the Python community agrees it should mean, but it does not affect the behavior of your programs.

The underscore prefix is meant as a hint to another programmer that a variable or method starting with a single underscore is intended for internal use. This convention is defined in PEP 8.

This isn’t enforced by Python. Python does not have strong distinctions between “private” and “public” variables like Java does. It’s like someone put up a tiny underscore warning sign that says:

“Hey, this isn’t really meant to be a part of the public interface of this class. Best to leave it alone.”"

https://dbader.org/blog/meaning-of-underscores-in-python

My additional recommendations:

- I noticed some of your indents are not within the first function that you've written.  I would double check all the indents to make sure the code is being included.